# PyMongo SON Manipulator/transform not working (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I'm trying to use a manipulator to convert decimal to float before saving to MongoDB. The data is coming from a SQL Server database, and I'm importing using pymssql, which is based of freeTDS.

I've followed the instructions from MongoDB docs, but I keep getting the error:

```
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pymongo\collection.py", line 467, in insert_one
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pymongo\collection.py", line 430, in _insert
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: Decimal('5019.13')
```

Here is my code for the transform:

```
import decimal
class Transform(SONManipulator):
    def transform_incoming(self, son, collection):
        for (key, value) in son.items():
            if isinstance(value, decimal.Decimal):
                son[key] = float(value)
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                son[key] = self.transform_incoming(value, collection)
        return son
```

where I add it to db:

```
def get(collection):
    client = MongoClient(uri)
    db = client[database]
    db.add_son_manipulator(Transform())
    return db[collection]
```

and when I call

```
collection = get('mycollection')
collection.insert_one(object)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [MongoDB Changelog](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html), since MongoDB 3.0, SONManipulator API is deprecated and won't work on `db.insert_one()`:

> The SONManipulator API has limitations as a technique for transforming
>   your data. Instead, it is more flexible and straightforward to
>   transform outgoing documents in your own code before passing them to
>   PyMongo, and transform incoming documents after receiving them from
>   PyMongo.
>
> Thus the add_son_manipulator() method is deprecated. **PyMongo 3’s new
>   CRUD API does not apply SON manipulators to documents passed to
>   bulk_write(), insert_one(), insert_many(), update_one(), or
>   update_many(). SON manipulators are not applied to documents returned
>   by the new methods find_one_and_delete(), find_one_and_replace(), and
>   find_one_and_update()**.

It would however work on `db.insert()`, but it's being deprecated, too.

So you're better off writing your custom converter on the boundary between your applied code and the database.